# Insert space before number in PascalCase string

Tags: c#, string, space

I want to place a space before a number.

Say for example I have this PascalCase string: "SupportContactAddressLine1".

I want it to display "Support Contact Address Line 1"

I have tried this:

```
var s = PascalCase;

 for (var i = 1; i < s.Length; i++)
 {
  if (char.IsLower(s[i - 1]) && char.IsUpper(s[i]))
  {
    s = s.Insert(i, " ");
  }
 }
```

But the result is: "Support Contact Address Line1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for a digit too:

```
if (Char.IsLower(s[i - 1]) && (Char.IsUpper(s[i]) || Char.IsDigit(s[i])))
```

Answer (score 0):

A digit is not a letter, therefore there is no distinction between lower case and upper case, and `char.IsUpper('1')` returns `false`.

You should include the use of `char.IsDigit(...)` to check for digits.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
var res = Regex.Replace("SupportContactAddressLine100", "([A-Z])|([0-9]+)", " $1$2");
```